# Telegram php bot Получить имя пользователя после ввода комманды

Tags: php, api, telegram, бот

Как получить имя пользователя после ввода команда /start? 
Напимер посылаю ему сообщения "Привет, введите имя"

Как ответить ему "Привет, Андрей"?

В интернете вообще не нашел нормальных примеров. Использую официальную библиотеку для PHP https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py нашел пример на питоне, может кто-то сможет перевести под php?

Comment: Может и сможет. На фрилансе попросите, там вам за оплату всё переведут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть была в том, что я хотел каким-то образом запомнить, что от пользователя в данный момент ожидается некоторый ввод и в случае его получения ответить ему. В конечном счёте для этой цели я использовал массив, в котором просто хранил айдишники пользователей, от которых ожидается ввод и место, куда этот ввод попадет для обработки.

Например:

```
Введите ваше имя:
Алексей // Записали в БД, продолжаем
Введите ваш возраст:
19 // Записали в БД, продолжаем
Введите ваш рост 
1.85 // Записали в БД, продолжаем и тд
// Регистрация окончена, ввод больше не ожидается, можно использовать бот.
```

Сейчас для этих целей можно использовать "состояния" и другие фичи которые есть почти в любой библиотеке для ботов.

Answer (score 2):

Используя [вот эту библиотеку](https://github.com/ShamanHead/telbot) сделать подобное не составит труда:

```
    use \Telbot\Bot as Bot;
    use \Telbot\Inquiry as Inquiry;
    use \Telbot\InputHandle as InputHandle;

    $bot = new Bot('API_TOKEN');
    $InputHandle = new InputHandle();

    Inquiry::send($bot
            ,'sendMessage',
        [
            'chat_id' => $InputHandle->getChatId(),
            'text' => "Привет, ".$InputHandle->getUserFirstName()
        ]
    );
```

[image: Пример работы]